# Scala List methods: `remove` and `sort`

Tags: scala

I'm working out of "Programming in Scala (First Edition)", and I've gotten to some List methods. There are two methods it names that give me an error in the interactive shell: remove and sort. Here are the examples it gives:

```
val thrill = "will" :: "fill" :: "until" :: Nil

thrill.sort((a, b) a.charAt(0).toLowerCase < b.charAt(0).toLowerCase)

thrill.remove(s => s.length == 4)
```

When I try those in the console, I get errors that those methods aren't "`a member of List[String]`":

```
scala> util.Properties.versionString
res41: String = version 2.11.1

scala> val myList = "one" :: "two" :: "three" :: "four" :: Nil
myList: List[String] = List(one, two, three, four)

scala> myList.sort((a, b) => a.charAt(0).toLowerCase < b.charAt(0).toLowerCase)
<console>:9: error: value sort is not a member of List[String]
              myList.sort((a, b) => a.charAt(0).toLowerCase < b.charAt(0).toLowerCase)
                     ^

scala> thrill.remove(s => s.length == 5)
<console>:9: error: value remove is not a member of List[String]
              thrill.remove(s => s.length == 5)
```

So I thought maybe I was using a newer version (since this book appears to be written a few years back), and I consulted the [List documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/List.html#A). Both methods appear to be there in version 2.7.7 (the newest I could find). As you can see, I'm running 2.11.1.

Did these methods get remove from the List API since 2.7.7, or am I using them wrong?

Comment: It's strange that 2.7 is the newest documentation you can find, my version of google [pop ups most recent scala flavour](http://take.ms/GKFFI)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the darker times of scala 2.7 (it's more than four years ago!) your code would work just fine, but now, with 2.8+ you have to use different names for `remove` and `sort`:

```
import Character.{toLowerCase => lower}
myList.sortWith { case (a, b) => lower(a.charAt(0)) < lower(b.charAt(0)) }
// List(four, one, two, three)
```

There is also .sorted for default sorting

```
List(2, 5, 3).sorted
// res10: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 5)
```

and .sortBy(x => ...) to sort with some preparation (it's like sorted with ephemeral map):

```
val foo = List("ac", "aa", "ab")
foo.sortBy(x => x.charAt(1))
// res6: List[String] = List(aa, ab, ac)
```

And remove was replaced with filterNot (though, I think remove is more convinient name, even if it makes you think that collection is mutable, which is tricked Ven in his answer):

```
thrill.filterNot(s => s.length == 5)
// res9: List[String] = List(will, fill)
```

There is also, .filter, which does the opposite:

```
thrill.filter(s => s.length == 5)
// res11: List[String] = List(until)
```

It can be seen way more frequently in scala code.